# Changing grid-template-areas without media query?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to achieve the below layout without using media queries. The reason I'd prefer to not use media queries is that this content is embedded on a site with a sidebar on the left that can expand and collapse. When it's expanded, it takes up about 400px, and it takes up maybe 50 when it's collapsed. It expands and collapses based off of a user interaction, not screen-width, so there's no good way for me to detect if it's open or not from CSS. Because of this, there could be some errors in my layout if I use a media query based on the screen width, instead of the actual width of the content. Is there any way I can use something like `flex-basis` or `minmax` to achieve this layout without media queries?

```css
/* functional code */

.a1 {
  grid-area: a1;
}
.a2 {
  grid-area: a2;
}
.b1 {
  grid-area: b1;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 400px 200px 200px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
  
  grid-template-areas: 
    "a1 b1"
    "a2 b1"
    "a2 .";
}

/* Can I emulate this on the container width instead of the screen width? */
@media (max-width:1000px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "a1"
      "b1"
      "a2";
    grid-template-rows: 400px 600px 200px;
  }
  .b1 {
    width:300px;
    justify-self:center;
  }
}

/* other styling */
.grid {
  gap:8px;
}

.grid * {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.collapsed { display: none; }
@media (max-width:1000px) {
  .uncollapsed {
    display: none;
  }
  .collapsed {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="uncollapsed">Uncollapsed State (make screen smaller to see collapsed state)</div>
<div class="collapsed">Collapsed State (make screen bigger to see uncollapsed state)</div>
<div class="grid">
<div class="a1">
  A1
  <br>
  Top-left normally
  <br>
  Top when collapsed
</div>
<div class="a2">
  A2
  <br>
  Bottom-left normally
  <br>
  Bottom when collapsed
</div>
<div class="b1">
  B1
  <br>
  Right side normally
  <br>
  Middle row when collapsed
</div>
</div>
```

FYI: I ended up just using a `ResizeObserver` polyfill and some JavaScript. Definitely not ideal, but it seems like container queries are currently impossible without JS.

Comment: Is this what you ry to do ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vYYpPRj i do not really understand what you try to do .  for javascript you have also window.matchMedia that you can mix width checking on container offsetwidth an example with matchmedia https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/aboRWRe